# Trying to set a Navigation Link Items detail view in ForEach loop

Tags: swift, core-data, uikit

**Aim**
Trying to generate a navigation link, so that To Do list items that are fetched from the Core Data model will have a link to an "ItemDetailView", which will show more details about the individual To Do List item.

**Attempts**
I have tried adding the Navigation view at the top of the section before the For Each loop runs.

But Xcode threw these three errors 
#1 Cannot call value of non-function type 'NavigationLink<Text, ItemDetailView.Type>'

#2 Missing argument for parameter #1 in call / Insert '<#LocalizedStringKey#>, '

#3 Type 'ItemDetailView.Type' cannot conform to 'View'

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    //Three Variables are set
    //Environment sets the context
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    //Fetch Request to query the To Do List Items
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoListItem.getAllToDoListItems())
    var items: FetchedResults<ToDoListItem>
    // A State Entry to hold the entry in the text field.
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // List in the navigation field for the the list of text.
            List {
                Section(header: Text("New Item")) {
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Enter New Item...", text: $text)
                        //Button to save a new item for each To do in the to do list and also initialise the text view.
                        Button(action: {
                            if !text.isEmpty {
                                let newItem = ToDoListItem(context: context)
                                newItem.name = text
                                newItem.createdAt = Date()
                                
                                do {
                                    try context.save()
                                }
                                catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                                text = ""
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Save")
                        })
                        
                    }
                    Section {
                        // For each is to showeach of the items from Core Data.
                        NavigationLink (destination:ItemDetailView)(
                            ForEach(items) { toDoListItem in
                                VStack (alignment: .leading){
                                    Text(toDoListItem.name!)
                                        .font(.headline)
                                    Text("\(toDoListItem.createdAt!)")
                                }
                            }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                                guard let index = indexSet.first else {
                                    return
                                }
                                let itemToDelete = items[index]
                                context.delete(itemToDelete)
                                do {
                                    try context.save()
                                }
                                catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                            })
                        )}
                }
                
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("To Do List")
    }
    
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the error is in your second section. You add a single NavigationLink for the whole ForEach view, instead of its individual Views. The former can be done (even though I assume you actually want the latter), but you don't call your methods correctly. The error messages are a result of this improper declaration.

I tried and adapted your code, see below for a concrete implementation that should compile and run.

```
    import SwiftUI
    import CoreData

    struct ContentView: View {
    //Three Variables are set
    //Environment sets the context
   
    var items: [String]
    // A State Entry to hold the entry in the text field.
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section {
                    TextField("Add New", text: $text)
                    Button(action: {
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Add New")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    })
                }
                
                Section {
                    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: DetailView(name: item),
                            label: {
                                Text("\(item)")
                            })
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                        print("do your deletion")
                    })
                }
            }.navigationTitle("To Do List")
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var name: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is the detail for \(name)")
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(items: ["Chocolate", "Cookies", "Gummy Bears"])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found another solution in addition to the one above if anyone is interested.

I referred to the Apple Documentation for declaring the Navigation view: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationlink

Then I made some amendments which seemed to go the trick. So now the build compiles and works exactly how it should. But it doesn't show in the Xcode preview, so I may need to resolve something in the Content_Previews Struct.

Please see the code below:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    //Three Variables are set
    //Environment sets the context
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    //Fetch Request to query the To Do List Items
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: ToDoListItem.getAllToDoListItems())
    var items: FetchedResults<ToDoListItem>
    // A State Entry to hold the entry in the text field.
    @State var text: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // List in the navigation field for the the list of text.
            List {
                Section(/*header: Text("New Item")*/) {
                    HStack {
                        TextField("Enter New Item...", text: $text)
                        //Button to save a new item for each To do in the to do list and also initialise the text view.
                        Button(action: {
                            if !text.isEmpty {
                                let newItem = ToDoListItem(context: context)
                                newItem.name = text
                                newItem.createdAt = Date()
                                
                                do {
                                    try context.save()
                                }
                                catch {
                                    print(error)
                                }
                                text = ""
                            }
                        }, label: {
                            Text("Save")
                        })
                        
                    }
                    Section {
                        // For each is to showeach of the items from Core Data.
                        ForEach(items) { toDoListItem in
                            VStack (alignment: .leading){
                                NavigationLink (destination: ItemDetailView()
                                ){
                                    Text(toDoListItem.name!)
                                        .font(.headline)
                                    Text("\(toDoListItem.createdAt!)")
                                }
                            }
                        }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                            guard let index = indexSet.first else {
                                return
                            }
                            let itemToDelete = items[index]
                            context.delete(itemToDelete)
                            do {
                                try context.save()
                            }
                            catch {
                                print(error)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("To Do List")
        }
        
    }
    
    struct DetailView: View {
        var name:String
        var body: some View {
            Text("This is the detail for \(name)")
        }
    }
    
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```